# Svelte - pass variable from parent component to all its child components

Tags: javascript, svelte

I need to pass data from the parent component to all child components, maybe some 3-4 levels down the chain. Using events for this is not a very elegant solution.

Is there a way to define a global variable that would be accessible to all child components of the component?

I would rather not use params either, since there will be a lot of repetition.

Comment: You should have a look to the [svelte-store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store). It allow you to share reactive variables across multiple components. See an example [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores).

Comment: If I understood Svelte stores correctly - this won't work here. The data I want to pass is an instance of a custom store wrapper class that uses Svelte stores. The problem here is I will have many instances of the same component, so I need to make the child components aware of either the instance id or the class instance itself (ideal). I can pass the id via props, but it doesn't look nice when I have to do it in every component down the chain - though I will have to settle for that if there is no other way.

Comment: I guess there is a more elegant way to do this. The issue is I don't really know what you try to attempt. Maybe if you provide an workcase or example it will be easier to find a better logic :)

Comment: The exact work case would be a topic for a different question, but I will try to provide a simple example ;) Let's say you have a component like <Window/>. Now there can be many windows and each has its own unique id. The <Window/> has sub-components and these sub-components have to be aware of that id. It is possible to do with params, although the child components go a few levels down, so I was wondering if there is a way to define a global variable that would be automatically accessible to all children down the chain.

Comment: Could you create a new store instance for each `<Window/>´-component like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/f4e333623a49420f999c9079e3532497?version=3.26.0

Comment: Yes, but then that store has to be passed down to child components. Again, it can be passed by props, but it's not very elegant and it adds a lot of repetition to a complex app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is for this exact problem that the `ContextAPI` is included in Svelte

in your 'parent' you do

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte'

setContext('my-var', variable)
```

and in any of the children where you need it you can do:

```js
import { getContext } from 'svelte'

const variable = getContext('my-var')
```

This technique makes the *my-var* variable in all of the descendants.

Note that this variables is **not** reactive, if you need that you have to pass in a store instead of a regular variable.

Here it is in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext)

Comment: Excellent, I didn’t understand the need for `context` before. Here is an example REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/c6a1648bcb12484f9b2bcb9cf5d82d7a?version=3.26.0 Is there cleaner way to instance a `store` than `export const st=function() {this.s=writable(0)}`?

Comment: for a simple one like that? just a function that returns a store would do I guess `export const st = () => writable(0)` and you just call `const s1 = st()`

Comment: @grohjy: ou do not need the {this.s = writeable(0)} You can {return writable(0)} and use let s = st() to instantiate a new store. And now (in your example) you only need to import c1 twice (as c1 and c2) in your app.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with `new`, I thought it should be used. Updated REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/c6a1648bcb12484f9b2bcb9cf5d82d7a?version=3.26.0

Comment: @voscausa thanks to you also. I’ve updated the REPL to include your comment. Now it’s nice and clean.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @grohjy: Behind the scene of 'new' function operator: https://medium.com/@chamikakasun/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-585919818afe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<script context="module">`

> A `<script>` tag with a `context="module"` attribute runs once when the
> module first evaluates, rather than for each component instance.
> Values declared in this block are accessible from a regular `<script>`
> (and the component markup) but not vice versa.

https://svelte.dev/docs#script_context_module